# Sum a List of averages in spring boot jpa query

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have this query thats return a list of averages

`@Query("SELECT AVG(p.quantity) FROM Position p GROUP BY p.client.id")                                            public List<Float> findAVGPositions();`

But I want to return SUM of averages like this, but it doesn't work

`@Query("SELECT SUM(averages) FROM (SELECT AVG(p.quantity) as averages FROM Position p GROUP BY p.client.id)") public Float findSumAVGPositions();`

Can you help me? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, in JPQL, nested selects are not permitted in `FROM` clause. They are allowed only in `SELECT` and `WHERE`.

You have two approaches available.

#### (1) Use `findAVGPositions` and calculate sum in Java

```java
    findAVGPositions().stream().reduce(0f, Float::sum);
```

#### (2) Use a native SQL query

```java
    @Query(value = "SELECT SUM(averages) " +
                   "FROM (SELECT AVG(p.quantity) AS averages " +
                         "FROM position p " +
                         "GROUP BY client_id) AS averages_select",
            nativeQuery = true)
    public Float findSumAVGPositions();
```

Depending on the database you use, `AS averages_select` alias might be needed or not (PostgreSQL requires it, even if it's not used).

Please, pay attention to use the correct names of a database table for `Position` entity and a database column for a foreign key `client.id`.

In my example, I assumed a standard mapping convention: `position` as a table name, and `client_id` as a foreign key column.